# Pointer Arithmetic using arrays

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

My question is that if you were print out the resulting *(ary + i), which I know is another way to say ary[i] value, would the following output be a hexadecimal/garbage data or would that specific index be assigned a new value based on the result computed from *ary + i? This whole pointer stuff still throwing me off.

```
  int ary[] = [7, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8];

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            *(ary + i) = *ary + i;
        }
```

Comment: Please consider indenting your code.

Comment: `ary[i] = ary[0] + i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ary` decays to a pointer in the expressions you posted. And since it always produces the same address (the first element), `*ary` will evaluate to `7` at every iteration.

Since you understand that `*(ary + i)` is equivalent to `ary[i]`, you should now gather that your loop body is akin to this:

```
ary[i] = 7 + i;
```

Comment: *"*ary will evaluate to 7 at every iteration."*, which is true only because first iteration doesn't change that value.

Answer (score -1):

`int ary[] = [7, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8];` is **wrong assignment method,**

one must use `{  }` to assign values to array.

So, correct way to define is:
`int ary[] = {7, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8};`

Here `*(ary + i)` is **equivalent** to `ary [i]` , and `*ary + i` is **equivalent** to `ary [0] + i`.

Addressing your question, **no it won't throw hex or garbage,** you have **dereferenced** a pointer, so it will give the data stored at that location.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

 int main ()
  {
      int ary[] = {7, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8};
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      { 
          *(ary + i) = *ary + i; 
      }

      for (int j=0;j <8;j++)
      {
          std::cout <<ary [j];
       }
    }
```

Output:

```
7891011121314
```

Hope you draw the correlation.

**if this helps great, if it doesnot, indicate so in comments, willing to edit**

Comment: `*ary + i` is *not* equivalent to `ary [i] + 1` it is equivalent to `ary[0] + i`(not the downvoter btw)

Comment: also Storyteller appears to have given a full and correct answer six minutes before you - but you might have started writing your answer before you saw that.

Comment: Yess..it seems...so